# how can I read Object (java.lang.Object) in java

Tags: java, android, object

I have one Object and it contains value as shown in picture.
But when i log its value but it not give me value

Please see image. at the time of debugging i am able to see array of value. Can any one please tell me how can i get this value.?

```
Loger.d("TAG", "loop called  " + object.toString());
```

**Output :**

```
loop called  [Ljava.lang.Object;@41ea9df8
```

[image]

Any Help Would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

Its not Object Array Its Object

```
@Override
public IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper(String connectionType, Object extra) {
    return createIOIOLooper();
}
```

this extra variable also shows me same value as like Picture.

Thanks

Comment: `object` is an array, so you need to use index to get values ex: `Loger.d("TAG", "loop called  " + object[0]);`

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString(object)` instead. And please change your color scheme while you still have functional eyes.

Comment: something i forgot to mention .. Object[] is an Object as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can print your Object

```
System.out.print(java.util.Arrays.toString(object));
```

since your object is an array, or you can use your object after adding an index to access the element in your array, like

```
Object objectOne = object[0];
Object objectTwo = object[1];
```

and so on

Comment: No i cant able to do this

Comment: @Sam_k can you override the toString() of this object or you cant reach it's source code ?

Comment: @Sam_k another thing you can do is casting this Object to the type you know what it it, like ((MyObject)object).getMethod() ...

Comment: I dnt Know Whats type of this Object. Its come from IOIO Library

Comment: @Sam_k i posted another answer to help you identify this object

Comment: Thanks Again for Answer. But i find the Object type from Library. `@Override
public Object getExtra() {
return new Object[] { device.getName(),
 device.getAddress() };
}`

Here device is `BluetoothDevice device `.

Answer (score 2):

You are logging the `array` directly, you need to iterate the `array` and then `log` the output.

From Java 5 you can do `Arrays.toString(arr)`

Comment: I am getting this error : he method toString(boolean[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Answer (score 1):

Now it seems that your problem is not knowing what the Object is so you cant Cast or deal with it as you like, so here is a piece of code using the java reflections "java.lang.reflect package" to identify any strange object you can see, and so you can realize what methods it contains and what it's type

```
public void identifyObject(Object object){

    Class objectClass = object.getClass();
    Method[] methods = objectClass.getMethods();

    System.out.println("Class Name : "+objectClass.getName());
    System.out.println("Class Type : "+objectClass.getSimpleName());

    System.out.println("Available Methods : ");
    for(Method method : methods){
        System.out.println(method.toString());
    }
}
```

now using this method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // the class that holds identifyObject() method
    Main app = new Main();

    System.out.println("identify Array :");
    int[] ints = new int[5];
    app.identifyObject(ints);

    System.out.println("-----------");

    System.out.println("identify object");
    Object object = new IOIO("un known object");
    app.identifyObject(object);

    System.out.println("////////////////");

}
```

and result is :

```
identify Array :
Class Name : [I
Class Type : int[]
Available Methods : 
public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()
public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
public final native void java.lang.Object.notify()
public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll()
-----------
identify object
Class Name : com.stackoverflow.ioio.IOIO
Class Type : IOIO
Available Methods : 
public char[] com.stackoverflow.ioio.IOIO.getChars()
public void com.stackoverflow.ioio.IOIO.setWord(java.lang.String)
public java.lang.String com.stackoverflow.ioio.IOIO.getWord()
public void com.stackoverflow.ioio.IOIO.setChars(char[])
public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()
public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
public final native void java.lang.Object.notify()
public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll()
////////////////
```

hope this helps you cast your object to the right Type and use it the way you like

Comment: Thanks Again for Answer. But i find the Object type from Library. @Override public Object getExtra() { return new Object[] { device.getName(), device.getAddress() }; } Here device is BluetoothDevice device .

Comment: well as you say this method returns object[] ... i myself am now confused here :) sorry if i couldn't help about this ... maybe more clarification to your question will help here